# Hichcharts Add Button to toggle between Series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on Highcharts and trying to toggle between series with click of buttons - switch on and off a series from a button rather than the legend. Can we do it using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `chart.series[seriesNumber].hide()`.  reference [https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#hide]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            data: [120, 20, 50, 100, 510, 345, 120]
        }, {
            data: [132, 240, 444, 424, 230, 350, 330]
        }]
    });

    // the button action
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
   $('.button').click(function(){
       var seriesNumber = this.value;
        var series = chart.series[seriesNumber];
        if (series.visible) {
            series.hide();
        } else {
            series.show();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
    width: 150px;
}

#container {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="0"></input>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="1"></input>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```